# Determine if a web part is being rendered on a Web Part Page or WikiPage?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

How to programatically determine if a web part is being rendered on a Web Part Page or WikiPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type pageBaseType = this.Page.GetType().BaseType;
if (pageBaseType == typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage))
{
    // Wiki Page
}
else if (pageBaseType == typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage))
{
    // Web Part Page
}
```